# Anything wrong with the interval function. the way i have used it?

Tags: sql-server

```
select top 10 * 
from James.activity_gc a 
left join James.activity_gc as James.activity_gc1 b 
on a.user_id = b.user_id
and a.time = b.time - interval '1' day
```

Comment: Where did you get the specification for this interval function? Also, you've tagged MS SQL Server as well as google bigquery. Which of these are you using?

Comment: I am using both of these . But if i get through for either one is good

Comment: What happens when you try it? If you haven't even tried it, you should have before posting. And if you have tried it, you should be telling us what happened.

Comment: I have tried before posting it here -  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Answer (score 1):

The question is tagged `sql-server`, but Sql Server does not use the `Interval` keyword. Instead, you do it like this:

```
select top 10 * 
from James.activity_gc a 
left join James.activity_gc as James.activity_gc1 b 
    on a.user_id = b.user_id
    and a.time = DATEADD(day, -1, b.time)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works in SQL Server. Thank you Joel. Is there anything similar in Google Big query ? If you please help .

Comment: Just figured it out for Big query as well. Everything is working fine!!! Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For MSSQL Server, You could try

```
select top 10 * 
from James.activity_gc a 
left join James.activity_gc as James.activity_gc1 b 
on a.user_id = b.user_id
and DATEDIFF(day, a.time, b.time) = 1
```